# Start a Windows web server in the background with Ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible

I am looking to start a Go web server (a single .exe) on Windows Server via Ansible.

The equivalent in Linux that works great looks like:

```
- name: Start web server
  become: true
  become_user: root
  shell:
  cmd: nohup /home/centos/webserver </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I can do it in PowerShell using `Start-Process -FilePath -NoNewWindow .\webserver.exe` but it terminates when I close the PowerShell window.

I have also looked into doing it with `Start-Job { & C:\Path\to\webserver.exe }` and `Get-Job` shows it completed, but not sure what that means since it's a web server and should just keep running until it's killed.

I need something that will star the webserver but not be tied to the shell so Ansible can do it via the `win_shell` module. I would have hoped this would work, but no luck:

```
- name: Start the webserver processes
  win_shell: Start-Process -FilePath .\webserver.exe
  args:
    chdir: C:\Users\Administrator
```

Any and all suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was trying to find a more complicated way to do it with PowerShell when Ansible had built in functionality all along. This achieves exactly what I want:

```
- name: Start webserver
  win_shell: .\webserver.exe
  args:
    chdir: C:\Users\Administrator
  async: 180
  poll: 0
```